# How to add a new node in <v-treeview> Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently making a tree view using Vuetify. The tree view uses this structure:

```
      items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Applications :',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Documents :',
      children: [
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'vuetify :',
          children: [
            {
              id: 7,
              name: 'src :',
              children: [
                { id: 8, name: 'index : ts' },
                { id: 9, name: 'bootstrap : ts' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          name: 'material2 :',
          children: [
            {
              id: 11,
              name: 'src :',
              children: [
                { id: 12, name: 'v-btn : ts' },
                { id: 13, name: 'v-card : ts' },
                { id: 14, name: 'v-window : ts' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      name: 'Downloads :',
      children: [
        { id: 16, name: 'October : pdf' },
        { id: 17, name: 'November : pdf' },
        { id: 18, name: 'Tutorial : html' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 19,
      name: 'Videos :',
      children: [
        {
          id: 20,
          name: 'Tutorials :',
          children: [
            { id: 21, name: 'Basic layouts : mp4' },
            { id: 22, name: 'Advanced techniques : mp4' },
            { id: 23, name: 'All about app : dir' }
          ]
        },
        { id: 24, name: 'Intro : mov' },
        { id: 25, name: 'Conference introduction : avi' }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

My problem is in adding a new node to this structure, For example if I want to add a child under applications then the code would probably look like this:

```
this.items[0].children.push(newObject)
```

Or if I want to add under src? then it might look like this:

```
this.items[1].children[0].children.push(newObject)
```

If I want to go deeper then it might look like this:

```
this.items[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children.push(newObject)
```

As you can see, the way I add a node varies and the code changes depending on the location and depth of where I want to add the node. That means there is no single code that will cater for all the locations. Also I can add and nest as many node as I can. *example is google drive* How should I go about this? I've run out of ideas and is looking for any suggestions that might help.

Comment: One thing you could do is to iterate through these nodes and find one by the `id` or `name` then simply `.push()` the new item onto the `children`.

Comment: @jom Can you please give an example on how to use Vue.set() with my example above. I read about Vue.set() and the way I understood it is that it just makes it reactive. Thank you for you suggestion by the way.

Comment: I posted something that might give you an idea how this could be done. [Check this out](/a/54618376/3634538).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are adding nodes directly from the tree, the easiest way is by using scoped slots. For example, you can use the `append` slot to add something to each item. Since the item is passed to the slot, you can pass it to a function that can easily add a child to that object.

```
<v-app>
  <v-treeview :items="items">
    <template slot="append" slot-scope="{ item }">
      <v-btn @click="addChild(item);">Add child</v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-treeview>
</v-app>
```

```
addChild(item) {
  if (!item.children) {
    this.$set(item, "children", []);
  }

  const name = `${item.name} (${item.children.length})`;
  const id = this.nextId++;
  item.children.push({
    id,
    name
  });
}
```

Otherwise just walk recursively through the tree until you find the item you want to add to.

```
findItem(id, items = null) {
  if (!items) {
    items = this.items;
  }

  return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (acc) {
      return acc;
    }

    if (item.id === id) {
      return item;
    }

    if (item.children) {
      return this.findItem(id, item.children);
    }

    return acc;
  }, null);
}
```

You can see an example in codesandbox.

[image: Edit How to add a new node in <v-treeview> Vuetify]